# What is the functional difference between react-router's <Route path='/' > and <Route path='*' >

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am studying React now and came across this question.

Many tutorials tell me to use `exact` option such that `<Route exact path='/'>` can route to homepage.

But I learned that if I remove the `exact` option, it will match *all the time*.

With that in mind, what would be the difference between using the wildcard symbol for the path `*` and using `/` without `exact` option? And what would be an incentive to use one or the other?

Comment: ReactJS does not ship with a router.  So, you must be using react-router.  What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: Seems like you can also omit the `path` for same result : Routes without a path always match. [doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string)

Comment: @DavinTryon I am using `react-router-dom v4.2.2`

Comment: @GabrielBleu Good point. However, I wish I learned if there is any reason to use one or the other.

Comment: @JunPark In case you haven't seen it, their documentation is quite [extensive and well written](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-render-methods)